# How to use array notation to append data from different tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want the yellow highlighed data append vertically (right next to "Paul Hill").   Thank you so much for your help.

={'HR 2010'!A2:C5,'HR 2020'!A2:C5}

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1malF_5AEMuq3HCZ4G0SXkDJk3x_Vrdgcu4gzdA0HnPA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for vertical use:

```
={'HR 2010'!A2:C5;'HR 2020'!A2:C5}
```